# What user mounts an nfs share?

Tags: mount, iptables, nfs

On a CentOS7 client, running **mount** as root (in all cases), if I use this iptables rule-

```
-A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2049 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

...the NFS4 mount goes through fine.

But if I limit the rule to the root user-

```
-A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2049 -m owner --uid-owner root -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

...iptables blocks the mount. In **/var/log/messages** I see-

```
Dec 7 14:00:29 nfsclient kernel: IPtables DROP DEFAULT OUT: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=<client IP> DST=<server IP> LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63737 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=987 DPT=2049 WINDOW=26883 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

...which begs the question, *"who mounts the NFS share?"* or *"why does IPtables block when the root user is specified?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `iptables -m owner --help`:

```
owner match options:
[!] --uid-owner userid[-userid]      Match local UID
```

You need to specify a UID, not a username.  So instead, try:

```
-A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2049 -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Oh!! I cannot believe I missed that- thank you.